# Combine sizeof string and chararcter

Tags: c++, sizeof

The last 2 cout statements have the same size. why?

```
int main() 
{
char ch=127;
cout<<sizeof(ch)<<endl;    //Size=1
cout<<sizeof("Hello")<<endl;    //Size=6
cout<<sizeof("Hello"+ch)<<endl;    //Size=8
cout<<sizeof("HelloWorld"+ch)<<endl;    //Size=8
return 0;
}
```

Please explain.
Thanks

Comment: `"Hello"+ch` does not append `ch` to the string literal. Use `std::string` for strings in C++ if you want more intuitive behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `"Hello"+ch` the array containing the string `"Hello"` decays to a pointer to its first element, and you add `ch` to this pointer.

The result of pointer arithmetic is a pointer, which is what you get the size of.

---

Equivalent code would be something like

```
char const hello[] = "Hello";
char const* phello = hello;  // equivalent to &hello[0]
char const* result = phello + ch;
cout << sizeof(result) << endl;
```

Comment: Unless you have an operator defined which can handle this case and then you get the size of the operators result. But without that it gives you the size of a pointer which in todays 64Bit systems is, well, 64 Bit and therefore 8 Bytes.